# I have a list of coefficients and I am trying to make a power series. How?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I noticed the `Series[]` command that would be perfect for Taylor polynomials. Unfortunately, I do not have the function available. I just have a list with the coefficients. How can I make a Taylor Polynomial with the list of coefficients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the Taylor series with [`SeriesData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html):

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6}]

(*    1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + O[x]^4    *)
```

`SeriesData` is flexible enough to do [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), not just Taylor and Laurent series.

Comment: I recommend against this method. There is an internal validation stamp needed for `SeriesData` objects so that code downstream will know it was created by `Series`. I would instead do, say, `{1, 1, 1/2, 1/6}.x^Range[0,3]+O[x]^4`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, the first example in the documentation tab "Survey of the scope of standard use cases" of [`SeriesData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) is "Construct `SeriesData` explicitly", followed more-or-less by what I wrote. While I appreciate your warning and generally would prefer using [`O`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) directly as you suggest, maybe your comment on esoteric validation stamps should be made to appear somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's safe. Generally the ones that are not validated get passed into evaluation code that will validate them. A little slower than having them pre-validated, but I guess it will work okay.